# Using Pyhton for loop, how can I take a letter from a string every time without any repeatation

Tags: python, anagram

'''
Create a random anagram of a string.
Use the choice method to create 5 random anagram of a string.

Expected Result: Anagram consisting of every charcters of '`CREATE`'.

```
Output : 
Anagram# 1: taeecr 
Anagram# 2: aaaete 
Anagram# 3: acteet 
Anagram# 4: rcrcee
Anagram# 5: aeerca
```

'''

```
from random import choice
Orig = 'create'
OrigL = list(Orig)
AnagL = []
for a in range(5):
    AnagL = []
    for i in range(len(Orig)):

        p = choice(OrigL)
        AnagL.append(p)
    Anag = ''.join(AnagL)
    print('Orig#',a+1,Orig)
    print('Anag#',a+1,Anag,'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following, without `random.choice`:

1. Convert the string to a `list`
2. Shuffle the list
3. Join the list back

As such:

```
from random import shuffle
word = list('create')

for i in range(5):
    shuffle(word)
    print("Anagram #{}: {}".format(i+1, "".join(word)))
```

---

```
Anagram #1: aeetrc
Anagram #2: rcteea
Anagram #3: eertca
Anagram #4: tceear
Anagram #5: erecat
```

---

Using `random.choice`:

1. Convert the original string to a `list`
2. Use `random.choice` to get a random **index** from the list
3. Pop that index and save the character
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until the list is empty
5. Repeat steps 1-4 until you have 5 anagrams

Comment: The phrasing of the question specifically calls for the use of the `choice` method.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron which makes me think it is for homework. I offered an alternate solution, and the pseudocode for implementing with `choice`.

Comment: It is homework, and OP's code is actually almost correct. The only thing that is left to do is pop out the chosen letter. Also, there is not need to convert original string to list. `choice` will select a character out of a string, and `s.replace(c, "", 1)` can be used for popping.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron wonderful, consider clicking the "Post Your Answer" button below.

Comment: Thank you, @AmitaiIrron . I understood it now. Btw, its not for homework. I am trying to learn pyhton from Heinhold's book. :)

Comment: @MohammadArafatIntisher - I have nothing against homework, especially when you assign it to yourself, based on self-learning from a book. There is also value in forcing yourself to rely on lower-level functions, instead of  going straight for the pre-cooked solution.

Comment: A suitable lower-level function would be `randint`. Doing `choice(range(...))` feels like a long-winded way round to achieve that, even though I accept that the alternate solution was constrained by the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choice



Orig = 'create'
OrigL = list(Orig)
AnagL = []

for a in range(5):
    AnagL = []
    notAnal=Orig
    for i in range(len(notAnal)):
        p = choice(notAnal)
        notAnal=notAnal.replace(p,'',1)
        AnagL.append(p)
    Anag = ''.join(AnagL)
    print('Orig#',a+1,Orig)
    print('Anag#',a+1,Anag,'\n')
```

Comment: Btw, you mentioned 

p = choice(notAnal)

But choice works on Lists only.

Comment: This code works at python 3.8.
This is the result 25 - 4
30 - 2
31 - 3
33 - 1
38 - 0